# BIRT parse XML with XPath

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, birt

Very new to XPath expression and XML. I need to get SatNum, Priority and SatName from an XML file.
Here is the XML file:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<sats xmlns = "http://test/data">
    <sat SatNum = "900">
        <satName Priority = "1">
            <SatName>JOSH</SatName>
        </satName>
    </sat>
</sats>
```

Ive tried these XPath expressions and I still cant get any of the nodes.

```
/sats/*
x:sats
x:xmlns
/*[local-name()='sats']
/*[local-name()='xmlns']
/*:xmlns
/*:sats
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//sats/(sat/@SatNum,.//satName/@Priority,//SatName/text())
```

or

```
//sats[1]/(sat/data(@SatNum),sat/satName/data(@Priority),sat/satName/SatName/data(text()))
```

Output:

> 900
>
> 1
>
> JOSH

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I've tried both and I get the following error:
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token. I am very new to XPath so I'm not quite sure what this means.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token

Comment: @1122335 - Check if your processor supports xpath 2.0 syntax (which is what the above is). If it only supports xpath 1.0, this won't work.

Comment: It does not support xpath 2.0. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @1122335 - Sorry about that; I should have asked you about that first....